# Wordpress Page not reading css properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My wordpress page is skipping a css class, and it doesn't show well. It has no padding.

In my wordpress theme, all the pages have the .page .hentry class inside their class attribute.

The page "Ask" has this html code:

```
<article id="post-70" class="post-70 page type-page status-publish hentry">...
```

And works ok, but my Questions page don't

```
<article id="post-69" class="post-69 page type-page status-publish hentry">...
```

When I see the code with chrome, the article has the .hentry class only.

This is part of the css code:

```
.hentry {
    margin: 0 0 45px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.page .hentry {
    padding: 45px;
}
```

This is the link to the [page with the problem](http://thejuankyblogs.com/foro), and [the other page](http://thejuankyblogs.com/foro/ask/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.page .hentry` means that it adresses elements with class `hentry` *inside* a parent/grandparent etc. element with class `.page`

Look at the classes in the `body` tag: The one page has class `page` in the body, the other one `archive` (and no `page`) So the `.page .hentry` selector only applies to `.hentry`  in the page that has `.page` in its `body` tag, not the `archive` page.

if you want to address both, you can use `.page.hentry` as a selector (without a space in between) - this will apply to all elements that have both `.page` AND `.hentry` classes .

Answer (score 1):

The page that works has `.page` on the body class but the one that doesn't is missing that class from the body.

The selector is:

```
.page .hentry {
    padding: 45px;
}
```

but if `.page` is not present it will skip it.

Solution, they both use `#main` so change the css to:

```
#main .hentry {
    padding: 45px;
}
```

or just add the padding to:

```
.hentry {
    padding: 45px;
    margin: 0 0 45px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Here is an another alternative:

```
.page.hentry {
    padding: 45px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that other pages uses #main and .hentry so I can't change them. I tried to add the .page class to the body with jquery, but it didn't work.

Comment: then use .page.hentry {} do any other pages use that, they need to be joined together meaning both .page & .hentry are applied to the article element

Answer (score 0):

First, we need a jsfiddle/similar snippet to help you to solve your problems.

But my tip is, go to your theme folder(inside content/yourthemename) and inspect with some code editor like [ATOM](https://atom.io/) or [SUBLIME](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and look for where's question page is being generated.